# Get selected route or route index

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google maps javascript api and have something working just fine including waypoints and display, however i ask Google for alternative routes (typically get 3 back) and the direction panel displays them as a choice.

I couldn't find anything in the doc that lets me know what choice the user made, is there an event i could respond to or something built in for that?

Comment: Can you post sample working code to JSFiddle?  I suspect the directions panel might have an identifier that you could then attach an event listener to for clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the index of the selected route you may get via the method `getRouteIndex` of the DirectionsRenderer.

A possible event to detect changes on the routeIndex is `routeindex_changed`.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsRenderer,'routeindex_changed',function(){
     //current routeIndex
     console.log(this.getRouteIndex());  
     //current route
     console.log(this.getDirections().routes[this.getRouteIndex()]);   
  });
```